# DDE server Error UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java

I followed a tutorial that create DDE server but i get this error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.neva.ExternalObject.toExternalHeap(Ljava/lang/String;)
the tutorial is here :

[JAVADDE](http://www.nevaobject.com/_docs/_javadde/JavaDde.htm)

Comment: seems you use different versions of your libraries

Comment: i used the setup file in the tutorial it create automatically the files in java home but not good enough (still error on code) so i imported javaDDE.jre and Courotine4java.jre to my project error are fixed but when i compile i get that error

Answer (score 0):

[UnsatisfiedLinkError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

Usually you need to add "java.library.path" parameter like

> `java -Djava.library.path="C:\dde" Example`

or put DLL to startup folder.

Also, if you will not be able to solve current problem you can try another [JDDE](http://jdde.pretty-tools.com) library.